# Share files from Virtual Box installed on Ubuntu to Windows 7 on Virtual Box

Tags: mount, virtualbox, xubuntu, windows-7

I have installed Virtual Box on Ubuntu and i need to create Oracle Data Base on Windows 7.
So, I need to share my Hard Drive files from Ubuntu to Windows 7 on Virtual Box.
I have tried many ways but i failed.
I have tried this command `sudo mount -t vboxfs -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host`
, But this **error** shows up `mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxfs'`

[image: Shared folders is active]
[image: Error]

Comment: Are guest additions installed in the Windows guest?

Comment: I don't know, How i can do so?

Comment: See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows